# Reading doubles from a .txt file

Tags: java, file, double, filereader

I'm trying to read a .txt file which has a line of 3 elements, the first being a string such as "tri" and then the next two are doubles like 2.3 and 4.2. The problem is, I keep getting a compiler error when I try to read the next double. If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it. This is my problematic code:

```
            if(order.equals("printAll"))
            {
                printAll();
                if(textReader.hasNext())
                {
                    order = textReader.next();
                    if(textReader.hasNextDouble())
                    {
                        dimension1 = textReader.nextDouble();
                        dimension2 = textReader.nextDouble();  <---**this line**
                    }
                }
            }
```

The line I pointed at keeps giving me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at arrayDrawer.main(arrayDrawer.java:88)
```

Line 88 being the line I pointed to. Sorry if it's vague, I will post more of my code if need be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Input for the program:

```
rec 4.2 4.0
tri 4.9 9.3
tri 2.1 9.9
compAreaAll
printAll 
del 4.9
printAll
```

Comment: are they on the same line and separated with some character?  Like a comma separated line?

Comment: The text file would read like this: tri 5.0 3.4 \n rec 4.6 2.4

Comment: Looks like this should work.  I suspect your input file is corrupt.  Can you cut-and-paste its contents in your question?

Comment: @lreeder rec 4.2 4.0
tri 4.9 9.3
tri 2.1 9.9
compAreaAll
printAll
del 4.9
printAll

each string uses scanner to call a method, and the doubles are read then multiplied

Comment: I added this input to your question.  Please fix if it's not right.  If this is the input, then you code is having problems processing the "del" order because it is not followed by two doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that input, your program is reading the final "printAll", then "del" as the order number, then "4.9" as a double, then it tries to use nextDouble to read the final "printAll" and fails.  The order "del" should be followed by two doubles.